# PHPUnit out of box not working on OSX

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Installed PHPUnit via PEAR and copied the latest repository from https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/

Wrote a basic test and saved it in the root directory (also tried /Tests/)

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
class CalculatorTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{
    public function testAdd(){
        $c = New Calculator();
        $result = $c->add(5, 10);
        $this->assertEquals(15, $result);
    }
}
```

Throws errors about not being able to load `require_once(SebastianBergmann/Diff/autoload.php)` In the `PHPUnit/Autoload.php` there is three lines, 69, 70 and 71.

```
require_once 'SebastianBergmann/Diff/autoload.php';
require_once 'SebastianBergmann/Exporter/autoload.php';
require_once 'SebastianBergmann/Version/autoload.php';
```

The directory `SebastianBergmann` doesn't even exist.... why are these lines in here?

What am I doing wrong, did I copy from the wrong place?

Also trying to run `/Tests/Runner/BaseTestRunnerTest.php` fails with `Class 'PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner' not found`

Comment: "and copied the latest repository from" --- ? So you just cloned the master branch?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just clone it and expect to work. Either completely install via [PEAR](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/installation.html#installation.pear) or [composer](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/installation.html#installation.composer).

As of those particular references - they are satisfied as composer dependencies: see here https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/composer.json#L32

Comment: I already did install it via PEAR. Unfortunately the documentation is rather lacking. Says to run two lines, then what?

Comment: "I already did install it via PEAR" ... "and copied the latest repository from"

Comment: Working? how is it working, I don't see anywhere where I can setup a test? it installs into `/Users/admin/pear/bin/phpunit` which is a singular file

Comment: @Bankzilla: open it and see that it includes additional files from somewhere else. "I don't see anywhere where I can setup a test" --- in any directory on your computer

Comment: So what's the framework for if you can't use it? I'm new to the whole unit testing, so having no physical files and folder structure to layout a testing environment seems very confusing

Comment: @Bankzilla: you can use it right after you've installed it. "having no physical files and folder structure to layout a testing environment seems very confusing" --- it's up to you how you organize it. Google for "phpunit tutorial" (like https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-introduction-to-phpunit/) and read phpunit documentation to get it sorted